# I have a question regarding active campaign

Tags: node.js, serverless, activecampaign

I have a question as I want field value numbers (i.e  field: "1") while updating contact in Active Campaign. I can't find anything authenticate in Active-campaign documentation.

Comment: Question is unclear. Please provide more details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.